# Convert Directory Path to JSON Directory Tree Representation

Tags: c#, json, tree, filepath

I have a sample output of the file paths, this is just an example the for the question

New Text Document.txt 
New folder/
New folder/README.txt

which I would like to convert to the following JSON

```
{
   "Data":"/",
   "Nodes":[
      {
         "Data":"New Folder",
         "Nodes":[
            {
               "Data":"New Text Document.txt"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Data":"New Text Document.txt",
         "Nodes":[
            ""
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My Node Class is the following

```
public class Node
    {
        public Node(string fileName)
        {
            Nodes = new List<Node>();
            Data = fileName;
        }

        public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out the algorithm, how to represent file paths in the as a Node class which I will serialize later to get the JSON. If there is any other way to represent file paths as Directory Tree structured JSON please suggest

Comment: Why don't you just use JSON serializer?

Comment: I'm serializing Node class, but my problem is, that I can't convert string path to the Node class representation to serialize it afterwards

Comment: You should make it more clear in your question that that's the problem.

Comment: Could should be able to split the path string on the char '/' and then iterate through each token, creating the child Node if it does not exist.

Comment: That's exactly where I'm stuck right now, I split the file path but afterwards I can't come up with solution how to create a child Node if it doesn't exists

Comment: Ever used recursion before?   :)  I can write an example real quick maybe

Comment: Kinda used thanks for the heads up :)) I would really appreciate the example on this issue.

Comment: @br4d.net any results?

Comment: which .net version u using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got around to making a sample for you. This should be a nicely scalable recursive solution. :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Node root = new Node("/");
    AddNode("New Text Document.txt", root);
    AddNode("New folder/", root);
    AddNode("New folder/README.txt", root);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class Node
{
    public Node() { Nodes = new List<Node>(); }
    public Node(string fileName)
    {
        Nodes = new List<Node>();
        Data = fileName;
    }

    public Node FindNode(string data)
    {
        if (this.Nodes == null || !this.Nodes.Any()) { return null; }

        // check Node list to see if there are any that already exist
        return this.Nodes
            .FirstOrDefault(n => String.Equals(n.Data, data, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    }

    public string Data { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}

public static Node AddNode(string filePath, Node rootNode)
{
    // convenience method. this creates the queue that we need for recursion from the filepath for you
    var tokens = filePath.Split('/').ToList();

    // if you split a folder ending with / it leaves an empty string at the end and we want to remove that
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tokens.Last())) { tokens.Remove(""); }

    return AddNode(new Queue<string>(tokens), rootNode);
}

private static Node AddNode(Queue<string> tokens, Node rootNode)
{
    // base case -> node wasnt found and tokens are gone  :(
    if (tokens == null || !tokens.Any())
    {
        return null;
    }

    // get current token, leaving only unsearched ones in the tokens object
    string current = tokens.Dequeue();

    // create node if not already exists
    Node foundNode = rootNode.FindNode(current);
    if (foundNode != null)
    {
        // node exists! recurse
        return AddNode(tokens, foundNode);
    }
    else
    {
        // node doesnt exist! add it manually and recurse
        Node newNode = new Node() { Data = current };
        rootNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        return AddNode(tokens, newNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; ///name space to use

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      string json = js.Serialize(pass node class object here);
```

Below code should give the desired directory  structure.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"path where to check";
    Node n = new Node();
    n.Nodes = new List<Node>();
    GetNodes(path, n);
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = js.Serialize(n);
}

public static void GetNodes(string path, Node node)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        node = new Node(path);
    }
    else if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        node.Data = "\\";
        GetFiles(path, node);

        foreach ( string item in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            Node n = new Node();
            n.Nodes = new List<Node>();
            n.Data = item;
            GetFiles(path, n);
            node.Nodes.Add(n);
        }
    }
}

public static void GetFiles(string path, Node node)
{
    foreach (string item in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        node.Nodes.Add(new Node(item));
    }

}

public class Node
{
    public Node()
    { }
    public Node(string fileName)
    {
        Nodes = new List<Node>();
        Data = fileName;
    }

    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in object serialization. Problem is how to transform string paths to Node object

Comment: Purely for this example no algorithm here 
Node root = new Node("/");
root.Nodes.Add(new Node("New Text Document.txt"));
root.Nodes.Add(new Node("New Folder"));
root.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new Node("New Text Document.txt"));
and after this if I will serialize the Node object like you noted I will get the result I want

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I can't use the Directory class because I am dealing with zip files but I will try to remake your code, thanks

Comment: Fine piece of code; it works but need to install a reference: **System.Web.Extensions**